# NHibernate HQL distinct and order by

Tags: nhibernate, hql

I've recently upgraded from NHibernate 1.2 to 3.1 in an old code base. I've fixed most problems but I'm stuck on this one. (I can't change from HQL to another access method without lots of changes to the codebase).

This wasn't an issue in 1.2, but after the upgrade I'm getting the following problem.

I have the following HQL:

```
select distinct c.OwnerUser from Film c order by c.OwnerUser.UserName
```

which results in the error:

```
[SQL: select distinct user1_.Id as Id33_, user1_.ApplicationId as Applicat2_33_, user1_.UserName as UserName33_, user1_.LoweredUserName as LoweredU4_33_, user1_.MobileAlias as MobileAl5_33_, user1_.IsAnonymous as IsAnonym6_33_, user1_.LastActivityDate as LastActi7_33_, user1_.CreateDate as CreateDate33_, user1_.CountryCode as CountryC9_33_, user1_.PreferredEditionId as Preferr10_33_ from dbo.tbl_Content film0_ inner join dbo.vw_aspnet_Users_With_Id user1_ on film0_.OwnerUserId=user1_.Id, dbo.vw_aspnet_Users_With_Id user2_ where film0_.discriminator in ('film', 'webcamfilm', 'slideshow') and film0_.OwnerUserId=user2_.Id order by user2_.UserName] ---> System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException: ORDER BY items must appear in the select list if SELECT DISTINCT is specified.
```

This code works fine, just with a duplicate entry I don't want.

```
select c.OwnerUser from Film c order by c.OwnerUser.UserName
```

How do I write the HQL to get distinct results?

Comment: Don't be in any rush to change from HQL to any other access method, we're also running NHibernate 3 and we're planning on changing all our other access methods to HQL eventually as the SQL generated by the other access methods isn't performant.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try specifying a join

```
select distinct owner from Film c join c.OwnerUser owner order by owner.UserName
```

Answer (score 0):

The error in this sql is clause `order by user2_.UserName`, but user2_.UserName can't be found in the select list, which happens to be a constraint for *select distinct* query.

Try

> select distinct c.OwnerUser,
>   c.OwnerUser.UserName from Film c order
>   by c.OwnerUser.UserName

then iterate through resulting list and get OwnerUser as (OwnerUser)list[i][0] or similar

Comment: Thanks, but I need to return the OwnerUsers direct from the query because of how the framework that's been put in place works.

Comment: even if i use this solution, the result isn't distinct the way i needed anymore

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the owner user has a unique id, you can use the following:

```
select c.OwnerUser from Film c where c.OwnerUser.id in ( select distinct c.OwnerUser.id from Film c) order by c.OwnerUser.UserName
```